AESCryptoServiceProvider encryption PKCS7 padding inconsistencies
I have inherited some legacy code originally built in .NET 4.6 which is something as follows:
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("B9519163"));
        }

        public static string Encrypt(string text)
        {
            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;

            aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WiPB5/SrFvq6fu93");   // Dummy IV value
            aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I9qKwOuZpWtt64Nl");  // Dummy key

            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
            }
        }


I'm building a new desktop application in .NET 8 that needs to decrypt data created by the legacy code and it's not working due to what seems to be incompatibility between how aes encryption/decryption works between the different .NET versions.
In .NET 4.6 the byte array dest returned by encrypt.TransformFinalBlock() has 32 bytes.
According my understanding of the PKCS7 documentation the remainder of the 32-byte array with all the padded bytes will have the same value. However, the padded bytes are being populated with seemingly random values. Here they are as seen in the debugger:
{245, 51, 180, 226, 20, 222, 24, 183, 72, 152, 102, 17, 219, 215, 37, 233, 123, 119, 154, 204, 218, 52, 139, 81, 119, 59, 42, 206, 13, 185, 247, 122}
I'm not sure if my understanding of how this is supposed to work is correct.
When I run the same code in .NET 8 it returns a 17-byte array which is not a multiple of the blocksize. The first 16 bytes are the same as expected.
{245, 51, 180, 226, 20, 222, 24, 183, 72, 152, 102, 17, 219, 215, 37, 233, 106}
How can I make my .NET 8 code backwards compatible to decrypt values generated by the legacy code? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

It's the plaintext that is padded, and you never see the plaintext padding unless you go out of your way to try and look at it.

I do not have a way to test .net 4.6, so I'll only be able to guess: try setting aes.FeedbackSize = 128 in .net 8.0 and see if the results are the same.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk - I did try setting aes.FeedbackSize = 128 in .NET 8. It returned a 32-byte array in dest but it had completely different values in it as compared to the .NET 4.6 version. In that sense it's not compatible and doesn't help with my objective.

I found the answer here to the first question about seemingly random numbers in the padded 32-byte returned in .NET 4.6.
That leaves the question as to why .NET 8 does not give the identical result.

Both codes use CFB8. In the .NET Framework, padding is generally required (though not for your sample data B9519163, as this is just 16 bytes in size due to the Unicode (=UTF16LE) encoding). This is actually a bug, as CFB is a stream cipher mode that does not require padding. In .NET 8, padding is (correctly) not required and therefore must be explicitly set to None. If this does not happen, the plaintext is padded with a 0x01 (for whatever reason).

In order to reproduce the (because of the padding actually wrong .NET Framework) ciphertext with .NET 8, the padding in .NET 8 must be explicitly disabled (None) and the plaintext must be explicitly padded with PKCS#7 (for the latter you need your own PKCS#7 padding implementation, you can find several on the web).

@Topaco - thank you very much for that insight. I see something to that effect here. I'm trying to implement your suggestion to do my own PKCS#7 padding implementation using BouncyCastle but not clear how to make it fully compatible with what is erroneously generated by .NET Framework.

Thanks to @Topaco for guiding me to the solution. Your help is much appreciated. Here's what I ended up with to solve this issue and make it backwards compatible with .NET Framework.
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("B9519163"));
    }

    public static string Encrypt(string text)
    {
        var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 256;

        aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WiPB5/SrFvq6fu93");
        aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("I9qKwOuZpWtt64Nl");

        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] paddedSrc = PerformPKCS7Padding(src, 16);

        using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(paddedSrc, 0, paddedSrc.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
        }
    }

    static byte[] PerformPKCS7Padding(byte[] input, int blockSize)
    {
        int paddingLength = blockSize - (input.Length % blockSize);
        byte[] paddedData = new byte[input.Length + paddingLength];

        // Copy original data
        Array.Copy(input, paddedData, input.Length);

        // Add padding bytes
        for (int i = input.Length; i < paddedData.Length; i++)
        {
            paddedData[i] = (byte)paddingLength;
        }

        return paddedData;
    }

